# How to get min value in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have few records and i want to create a query to give hourly records of a each divece battery level

What i did from timestamp field i extract date and select min function to get low value but as extract hour from timestamp is not aggragate function so i need to add in group by which now given me duplicate records. 
Here is my sql:

```
select extract(hour from observationtime) as hour,
       deviceid,
       min(batterylevel) as batterylevel 
from smartvakt_device_report 
where batterylevel!='' 
  and deviceid!='' 
  and observationtime between '2016-02-02' and '2016-03-02' 
group by observationtime,deviceid  
order by observationtime ASC, deviceid ASC
```

Here is above query output:
[image]

Here are actual records:
[image]

Can someone suggest how i can remove these duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Group by column Order to first Group by `deviceid` then by the `hour` using the same function `extract(hour from observationtime)`.

```
    SELECT
    deviceid, 
    extract(hour from observationtime) AS hour,
    min(batterylevel) AS batterylevel 
    FROM smartvakt_device_report
    WHERE
    batterylevel!='' 
    AND deviceid!='' 
    AND observationtime BETWEEN '2016-02-02' 
    AND '2016-03-02' 
    GROUP BY
    deviceid,
    extract(hour from observationtime)
    ORDER BY 
    extract(hour from observationtime) ASC, 
    deviceid ASC
```

Comment: Well it remove duplicate but now i am getting a maximum value of a batterylevel in a result why ?

Comment: strange! I'll try to recreate the issue with some dummy data

Comment: @user526206 I added some dummy data and checked it works for me. Can you add a sqlfiddle with some data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the hour, when you are grouping, you have to indicate that like this

```
group by extract(hour from observationtime)
```

Otherwise, `postgresql` will try to group together rows whose `observationtime` values are identical. But `observationtime` contains the time with full resolution, not just the hour.

Comment: By adding group by extract(hour from observationtime) return a maximum batterylevel value. however i am only interested in a minimum value

Comment: yea but result showing this data: deviceId: hour: batterylevel..  values    352794060238591: 11 :100,  
352794060238591 :12 :57

Comment: I am pretty sure that if do the `group by` as I suggested, it will work.

Comment: @redneb it should be grouped by first using device id, then only the hour